# How do I set a proper .htaccess file for 301 in bludit?

Tags: .htaccess

I have 12 old url .html an d want to redirect to new url without .html like that /blogpost.html > /blogpost. What I'm writing in .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Use Redirect:

```
Redirect permanent /blogpost.html /blogpost
```

Instead of twelve Redirect statements, one for each of your old urls, you could stuff them into a single, though probably a little confusing RedirectMatch, too:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/(blogpost|oldpage|ancienturl|longago)\.html$ /$1
```

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect and http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch for details.